# Cloud Dataproc API discovery

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I want to programmatically build against the Cloud Dataproc API but cannot find the discovery service. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discovery docs for the API can be [found here](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/dataproc/v1beta1/rest). The API explorer does not work but the API should be discoverable.